# Redirect Old URLs to New One in Prestashop 1.7.6.7

Tags: .htaccess, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

Can I get an answer to this issue I have?

Please need help on this Prestashop e-commerce issue.

example.com/en is still the same as example.com just that, initial, my store has two languages which are English(example.com/en) and French(example.com/fr). but now I installed i new version of my store and migrate all data only on one language which makes the domain be only example.com
so, Google has indexed many links and bookmarks. now I want to redirect all my related links which is example.com/en/.... so that the links can be updated and redirected to the new one example.com/..... because if old url is used, it has a 404 page.

any help, please?

Comment: Please any help yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved it myself.  added this code for redirection

this is just the answer in case you need it.

RedirectMatch 301 ^/en(.*)$ https://example.com/$1